# Watin Fix Google detects that a computer may be sending automated queries

Tags: c#, watin

I have a project that changing my computer proxy into another proxy (of another country), then using watin to auto search Google and then click on a indicated link. But the Google result is:

> We’re sorry... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now.

Sometimes Google requests a Captcha to ensure that I'm not a robot, sometimes it doesn't.

How can I cheat Google, I mean how can I prevent Google from detecting that I'm a robot? By using watin, C#? The problem is my changed proxy

Comment: `How can I cheat Google`...well...I'll just search that in Google!

Comment: @Arran I mean whether it has another way to change proxy that can cheat Google?

Answer (score -1):

Try sending your request like this: `link:your_request_text`. Usually this helps.